# Sent from one computer to another keystroke

Tags: c#, winforms

i know how to work with Keystroke and i know how to send any keboard typing

to any open windows to focus place the cursor on local computer.

i work with `GlobalKeyboardHook`

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

private string GetActiveWindowTitle()
{
    const int nChars = 256;
    StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
    IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();
    if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
    {
        return Buff.ToString();
    }
    return null;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

public void Start(string NAME)
{
    if (NAME.Contains("?")) return;
    MSG = lblMSG.Text.Trim();
    IntPtr zero = IntPtr.Zero;
    for (int i = 0; (i < 60) && (zero == IntPtr.Zero); i++) 
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        zero = FindWindow(null, NAME);
    }
    if (zero != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        string text = lblMSG.Text.Trim();
        text = text.Replace("gHook", "");
        foreach (char c in text)
            SendKeys.SendWait(c.ToString());
        if (MyParam._KeyAfter == "Enter")
        {
            MyParam.FromKEY = true;
            SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
        }
        else if (MyParam._KeyAfter == "TAB")
        {
            SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
        }
        else if (MyParam._KeyAfter == "Key Down")
        {
            SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN}");
        }
        SendKeys.Flush();
    }
}
```

now, i need to send some data to open windows on focus place using **RDP**

for any computer that in my net.

how to do it ?  my solution dont work

Comment: You should implement a client/server architecture to receive the commands from a remote computer and execute them on local computer

Comment: Describing how to work with [RDP](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16876.remote-desktop-protocol-documentation.aspx) will be too broad for SO question (assuming you find one who is expert in it)... Also "my solution dont work" is not very good explanation of a problem you are facing (which is even harder to do since you did not post any network related code).